# manejar eventos en mvc5 para pantallas tactiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, eventos

Me encuentro en la necesidad de desarrollar una aplicacion que funcionara en un totem: sin teclado, con pantalla touchscreen, la cual tengo pensado desarrollarla con ASP.net MVC 5 en .NET

He buscado informacion para el manejo de eventos, pero la verdad es que estoy medio perdido en este tema.

> ¿Alguien sabe cómo puedo lograr esto? ¿Alguna idea para poder comenzar a investigar al respecto?

Básicamente necesito poder capturar un evento de toque de la pantalla, y tambien necesito capturar un evento generado por algun sensor (acercar una tarjeta de identificacion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC5 es un plataforma de desarrollo web, los eventos son como cualquier dispositivo, click, mouseUp Mouse down, solo le das un tema [responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/) si es para un tótem.

Hay un montón de librerías tanto como para chrome o para java script que te dan la funcionalidad como de que aparezca el navegador en [full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre) y no deje al usuario minimizarla entre otras.

Ahora el tema de sensores, deberías manejarlo como un [servicio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zt39148a(v=vs.100).aspx) aparte, digamos lo siguiente, el lector tarjeta de identificación se acerca, eso hasta donde se envía por serial un bit que lleva los datos de identificación, estos los recibes y los envías a una base de datos, los cuales puedes estar constantemente consultado y ejecutarlo utilizando algún protocolo de conexion bidireccional puede ser Web Sockets ó [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr), que bueno este último es lo que yo siempre utilizo cuando desarrollo totems, tienen muchas funcionalidades, y hasta puedes reiniciar remotamente equipos. este tema es muy amplio, y te recomiendo primero empieces a revisar los links que te he puesto. Saludos

Comment: gracias por la informacion.